# Pagination with many to many relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `products`, `categories` and `category_product` (pivot) tables in my database.

I want to return the *category info* and *products* with *pagination* in **the same response**.

I know I can use `Product::with('categories')->pagination(20)`,

but I don't want to attach the category to each product.

What is the proper way to get products belong to a specific category?

I have tried that but I can't get the pagination with that:

```
$category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$products = $category->products()->paginate(20);
return response()->json([
    'category' => new CategoryResource($category),
    'products' => ProductResource::collection($products),
]);
```

Here is my ProductResource

```
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'description' => $this->description,
    'code' => $this->code,
    'image' => $this->image,
    'quantity' => $this->quantity,
    'price' => $this->price,
    'slug' => $this->slug,
    'sort_order' => $this->sort_order,
    'created_at' => $this->created_at,
    'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    'categories' => CategoryResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('categories')),
];
```

Comment: Can you include your `ProductResource` code please?

Comment: I've just added it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like an [issue with the way data is returned](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/paginate-while-returning-array-of-api-resource-objects-to-the-resource-collection) from the Collection.

The easiest solution is:

```php
return response()->json([
    'category' => new CategoryResource($category),
    'products' => ProductResource::collection($products)->response()->getData(true),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below

```
$category = Category::where('slug', $slug)
            ->with('products', function($query) {
                $query->paginate(20);
            })
            ->first();

return response()->json([
    'category' => new CategoryResource($category),
    'products' => ProductResource::collection($category->products),
]);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I've tried it but there is no pagination with that. I get 2 different products property under category.

Comment: You are correct, this way i am getting 20 elements but without the Paginator class.
But using your way i am getting the paginator, how is that you are not getting it?

`$products = $category->products()->paginate(20);`

Comment: Actually I get the pagination if I return $category->products()->paginate(20); but I can't get it when I add it to json response as an array element