# Laravel response()->json() disables pagination

Tags: php, laravel

I'm returning two Laravel Api Collections and to do so I'm using

```
 return  response()->json([
               'user' => new UserResource($contractor_user),
               'maintenance' => new MaintenanceCollection($contractor_maintenances),
         ]);
```

On the variable `$contractor_maintenances` I have a paginate method

```
$contractor_maintenances = Maintenance::filter($request)
                                            ->whereHas('contactedContractor', function ($query) use ($contractor_user_id) {
                                                return $query->where('user_id', '=', $contractor_user_id);
                                            })          ->with([
                                                'contactedContractor'
                                            ])
                                                        ->latest('maintenances.created_at')
                                                        ->paginate(2);
```

My problem is that if I return the maintenance collection on its own

```
        return new MaintenanceCollection($contractor_maintenances);
```

then the pagination works but when I call in two resources using

```
 return  response()->json([
               'user' => new UserResource($contractor_user),
               'maintenance' => new MaintenanceCollection($contractor_maintenances),
         ]);
```

the pagination meta data is not presented. How do I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I guess this looks similar to your question see the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65800917/853360

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pagination with many to many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763285/pagination-with-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that you can manually insert the pagination meta data in a JsonResponse like this:

```
return response()->json([
        'data' => new DataCollection($data),
        'meta' => [
            'total' => $data->total(),
            'currentPage' => $data->currentPage(),
            'lastPage' => $data->lastPage(),
            'perPage' => $data->perPage(),
        ],
        'links' => [
            'first' => $data->url(1),
            'last' => $data->url($data->lastPage()),
            'prev' => $data->previousPageUrl(),
            'next' => $data->nextPageUrl(),
        ],
    ]);
```